# Regex Find matched String from last

Tags: c#, regex

I have following String

```
Copy(objid1,objid2)
```

and i am using following regex for match

```
objid(?<id>\d{0,3})
```

however i looking output `objid2` and this regex returns `objid1`.

Is there any change would i do to find my desired output.
I thought that i will return all matched sub strings but returns only first one However i need only last matched sub string.

I don't want to use any sub string function as i don't know exact length to find .

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Please see my try.

```
Match output = Regex.Match("Copy(objid1,objid2)", @".*(objid(?<id>\d{0,3}))", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //objid(?<id>\d{0,3})

                    if (output.Success)
                    {
                        String ProcessString = ((System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture)(output.Groups[0])).Value;//output.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `.*` before the pattern you mentioned inorder to get the last match.

```
@".*(objid(?<id>\d{0,3}))"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xL5mA6/1)

Get the string you want from group index 1.

To get a last match in the multiline string, you need to enable DOTALL modifier.

```
(?s).*(objid(?<id>\d{0,3}))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xL5mA6/3)

Comment: This returns me String Copy(objid1,objid2 not objid2

Comment: print the group index 1 instead of index 0.

Comment: that is change `Groups[0]` to `Groups[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
,objid(?<id>\d{0,3})(?![^,)]*,)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/26